# Relevance of Segment names in EDI

Tags: erp, edi

I have been working with EDI documents for the past few months and dealt with different EDI formats like 810 (Invoice), 850 (PO), 855 (PO Ack) etc.

I just wonder where does this **Segment** names comes from? What is the exact definition for each segment? Like ISA, GS, GE, IEA etc.

Also beginning of a segment possess different values for each document formats. Like BIG for 810, BEG for 850 etc. Where does these abbreviations comes from?

Answer (score 0):

They come from the implementation guides. This is an example of one of them: http://www.att.com/Common/docs/EDI_820_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Traditional EDI (segments/elements) documents are defined by a governing standards body, usually ANSI (X12) or EDIFACT (U.N. standard). (TRADACOMS and HL7 are also standards bodies)  These entities created and published the document types, enveloping, segment names and definitions, element data types and size, component elements, etc.  http://www.x12.org/ is the main site for the X12 standard (predominantly found in the US).  EDIFACT can be found here: http://www.unece.org/cefact/edifact/welcome.html.  These groups are repsonsible for pushing the standard further as business requirements evolve and new data attributes are created.  Version 4010 in the ANSI X12 was the first Y2K compliant X12 standard released.  There have been many versions released since then, but many still use version 4010 as their standard.

The decision makers made some segments somewhat "mnemonic", so that you can easily determine what kind of information is in the segment.  BEG is a good example of this, as common sense would dictate it is "Beginning" of the transaction.  Of course, this doesn't apply consistently in the standard.  N1 for Names and Addresses, TD3 and TD5 for routing and lading qty.

The end users would then devise their own guideline as to how they implemented the standard.  In some cases you'll find some bastardization of the standard to fit special case needs.

Most translators come with some kind of built-in Dictionary Viewer where you can browse.  X12 is mostly closed-source and the commercial translator makers pay X12 to include the library.  EDIFACT (which is not your example above) is published free of charge.  There is a free tool from Liaison called EDI Notepad that you can download and get a sense of the syntax and validation.  That can be found here:  https://www.liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad/edi-dictionary-viewer/